# Triple integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\cos(\theta)} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2r\cos(\theta)}} r \ dzdrd\theta$ to find volume of a solid

Tags: integration, coordinate-systems, multiple-integral

On evaluating the volume between

$$x^2+y^2 = 2x\\z^2=2x$$

I set up the triple integral 
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\cos(\theta)} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2r\cos(\theta)}} r \ dzdrd\theta$$

for which Wolfram gives me the answer $\frac{128}{15}$ (which is correct). My work is shown below. I just cannot find the mistake that is producing the wrong result (even though the setup is ok):

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\cos(\theta)} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2r\cos(\theta)}} r \ dzdrd\theta = \\
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\cos(\theta)} r \sqrt{2r\cos(\theta)} \ drd\theta = \\
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2\cos(\theta)} d\theta \int_{0}^{2\cos(\theta)} r^{3/2} dr = \\
\frac{2}{5} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{2 \cos(\theta)} \cdot (2 \cos\theta)^{5/2} d\theta = \\
\frac{2}{5} \int_{0}^{2\pi} cos^3(\theta) d\theta = 0
$$

Comment: You are separating double integrals into single integrals when it is not allowed. Take a look at Fubini's theorem to see when you can avoid iterated nested integrals like this one. Unfortunately since you do not have constant bounds separating integrals like you have done is illegal.

Comment: @mikevandernaald What?

Comment: @bru1987 From the start, the bounds you indicate include some regions where $\cos\theta<0$ but you need $\cos\theta\geqslant0$ for the bound $\sqrt{2r\cos\theta}$ to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$x^2+y^2=2x\implies x\ge 0 \implies \cos(\theta)\ge 0\implies |\theta|\le \pi/$$

**SPOLIER ALERT**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> The integral extends in $z$ from $-\sqrt{2x}$ to $\sqrt{2x}$. So, we can write $$V=\iint_{R_{xy}}2\sqrt{2x}\,dx\,dy$$Now, upon transforming to polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, we note that the radial variable $r$ extends from $0$ to $2\cos(\theta)$ while the angular variable $\theta$ starts at $-\pi/2$ and ends at $\pi/2$.  We can write, therefore $$\begin{align}V&=\iint_{R_{xy}}2\sqrt{2x}\,dx\,dy\\\\&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\cos(\theta)}2\sqrt{2r\cos(\theta)}\,r\,dr\,d\theta\\\\&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac45 (2\cos(\theta))^3\,d\theta\\\\&=\frac45 \times 8\times\frac43\\\\&=\frac{128}{15}\end{align}$$as expected!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark